# Braid, Bastion showing black polygons

Tags: 12.04, games, intel, 3d

I just got the Humble Bundle 5 and am suffering severe graphical defects on Braid and Bastion.  Both games run but do not display properly. Sound, mouse etc. work fine.
Here are some screens of Bastion:

[image: Bastion graphic glitch]
[image: Bastion graphic glitch]

I couldn't get a screen of Braid.  I think its main problem is alpha support (all textures, even stair texttures etc., remain square and overlap the character).
I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with a Mesa Intel 915g graphics card (according to Amnesia :), which has no support whatsoever for my card). Is there anything I can install/fix to remedy these graphical problems, or do I need to fork over the cash for a new graphics card?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution? I couldn't find anything anywhere, but if you fixed it, maybe you could add the solution here as an answer for other people? Cheers!

Comment: No, I never found a solution. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

This helped me.

```
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

Comment: I already have it.

Comment: I found this question and answer by googling "ubuntu bastion black", and your apt-get command fixed the problem for me.  Bravo!

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. I noticed that, for Bastion, the problem only happens on an external monitor.

Comment: My son's running ubuntu 12.04 on an an old iMac with ati graphics and adding this library did the trick.